# query not running on heroku console

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku

I am really stuck with query on Heroku.

I am trying to run the following query on heroku console

```
SELECT DATE(TimeLogin) AS d, COUNT(*) AS c FROM histories GROUP BY DATE(TimeLogin)
```

but I get following error,

```
syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT,expecting $end

SELECT DATE(TimeLogin) AS d, COUNT(*) AS c FROM histor...
                         ^
```

My heroku has `postgresql`

Please let me know what is the problem with this query
Regards.

Comment: Did you add ";" at the end of query ?

Comment: What happens when you run the query using psql against your local database? How does that differ from what you get with pg:psql?

Comment: @TienNguyen nothing happened.

Comment: @dankohn i tried running query on local postgres, issue was with double quotes for columns.

Comment: You should answer your own question then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added double quotes for column names like this

```
SELECT DATE("TimeLogin") AS d, COUNT(*) AS c FROM histories GROUP BY DATE("TimeLogin")
```

this resolved my issue